# Parse multiple nested child node values of a parent node into a single output

Tags: xml, parsing, vbscript

I am trying to figure out how to run a query to grab every CCI_REF attribute data in the xml below and output the multiple values (CCI-000193, CCI-000192, etc) under each VULN tag into a single window. As you can see, some VULN tags will have just one CCI_REF and some may have more than one. I want the output to show only the CCI_REF values that belong to its own parent VULN tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CHECKLIST>
 <STIGS>
  <iSTIG>
   <VULN>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-1070</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000192</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000193</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000194</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
   </VULN>
   <VULN>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-1071</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000194</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
   </VULN>
  </iSTIG>
 </STIGS>
</CHECKLIST>
```

Below is the example code I have come up with so far. It will loop and display every instance of CCI-000XXX, but separately and not just in 1 output window per VULN tag. So wscript.echo will send 3 pop up windows rather than a single window with all 3 values listed. Does anyone know how to change the code to get what I need?

```
Set xmlDoc = _
  CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

xmlDoc.Async = "False"

xmlDoc.Load("C:\Test\test.xml")

strQuery = "/CHECKLIST/STIGS/iSTIG/VULN/STIG_DATA [VULN_ATTRIBUTE='CCI_REF'] /ATTRIBUTE_DATA"

Set CCI_Ref=xmlDoc.selectNodes (strQuery)

For Each objNode in CCI_Ref

wscript.echo objNode.text

Next
```

Comment: If you want to show all the values together, add the values to a variable in the loop and echo it after the loop? [BTW, `CCI_Ref.text` in your code should be `objNode.text`]

Comment: ahh thanks for catching that, I had it right in my script but must have been typing too fast when posting :/. Im not all that familiar with getting those values into a variable in the loop. I thought objNode was the variable?